# UIStackView Views are all on one row

Tags: ios, stackview

I have a problem with Views in a stackview where the different views are all showing on the same line and overlapping. This is in an app that used to be working so i'm not sure if this is a change to the language in some way. Does anyone have any idea why this is the cases and how to fix it?

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc5Bq.jpg)
[problem result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEHIJ.jpg)

Comment: I can't post more pictures due to reputation but the stackview options were: alignment=fill, distribution=equal centering, spacing=1, content mode=scale to fill, semantic=unspecified

Comment: Are you using autolayout toposition the labels?

Comment: I think so, I'm not very knowledgeable about ios... I added a bunch of constraints to the labels to have 0 top and bottom. Seems to have sorted it. Thx for your help